# Installing Ubuntu alongside an existing Windows system without creating a CD?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

[This Ubuntu help wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) says that, in order to add Ubuntu on an existing Windows system, I must burn Ubuntu on a CD first. But CDs are becoming less common these days, so I wonder if there is a way to install Ubuntu without burning it on a CD (or a DVD, or a USB stick) - just download the ISO to my Windows machine and then somehow install it as dual boot.

In the past I have tried to use Wubi for that purpose, but this was not stable, and got stuck too many times. So now I want to create a dual-boot system.

Comment: You can use a DVD - it does not have to be a CD.

Comment: I actually meant to ask if it is possible to install Ubuntu without burning it on any external device - CD, DVD or USB stick; just using the ISO image from Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Ubuntu without a CD or DVD or USB, you need to install Ubuntu as WUBI first, then migrate it to a hard drive partition using 'migrate-wubi'. This will work like a normal installation and won't be slow like WUBI. How to do this is written on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a CD you can check how to boot from a flash drive [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Just follow the instructions, then plug in your usb stick, reboot and set the boot sequence to your USB port in the BIOS menu. The rest is really straightforward.

Comment: I think I tried this in the past but it formatted my USB stick... Is there a way to install from USB without wiping its contents?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: I don't think so. But if the problem is to erase the content of your flash drive, you can simply make a backup of your data on your windows partition, then format the stick to make it ubuntu-bootable, install your dual boot, and finally restore your usb stick from the backup you made on windows.

Comment: You can use Lili for windows if you dont want to format your flash drive. It has an option to do it without formatting

Answer (score 1):

**From Ubuntu**

[USB installation Guide from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive)

There's a package called usb-creator-gtk (and usb-creator-kde for KDE-desktop).
It can be found in the Unity Dash
This application has a GUI to copy an iso/or from cd to a USB-drive and make it bootable.

**From Windows**

You can use the software [LinuxLive](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to create a Bootable USB in Windows.

[image]

Comment: If you dont need it to be formatted,Just uncheck the option format the key in FAT32 and it wont format your pendrive

Answer (score 1):

Using a USB stick works Great!
use [LILI](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) or [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).
Both methods are very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create bootable Ubuntu USB on Windows through Unetbootin software.

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Creating_a_bootable_Ubuntu_USB_flash_drive_from_Windows) link explains various methods of creating Ubuntu live USB on Windows.