# Ubuntu installation on Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, syslinux

Can anyone provide me with link of ubuntu setup(non .iso file) so that i can install it side-by-side on windows without writing on cd or usb flash drive?

Comment: Ubuntu is available at their official web site: http://www.ubuntu.com/ If you need instructions, your question is not clear. What do you mean by "without boot-up? What do you mean by "manual setup?" Please edit your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/432247/installing-ubuntu-on-an-existing-windows-system-without-creating-a-cd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the wubi installer. A very nice guide for that is available here. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide. I suggest you read it thoroughly and then step through it. I've used this method before with excellent results for clients who wanted to try Ubuntu but were uncomfortable with the idea of completely dumping windows.

**Edit:** It doesn't appear as if [the official wubi](https://launchpad.net/wubi/9.04) is currently in development, however an active fork  of the project can be found [here](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki) that supports all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. There are some differences between the official wubi and the fork, so it's a good idea to read the docs on the [home page](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki) as well as the related info for [Mok Manager.](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki/MOKManager)

Comment: That's best and simple solution.

Comment: Glad to help AmanJauhri!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the solution:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer
But anyone provided you with the same answer.
I have one Ubuntu 13.10 with Windows 7. Please avoid Windows 8.

Comment: I hv windows 7..:)